# xcode clean failed

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

Both my iPhone projects are sometimes giving a "build failed" error with no explanation of what the error is, and then a "clean failed" when I try to do a clean. I tty emptying the xcode cache but that doesn't seen to help. What normally clears it is re-starting my Mac. However, that has just failed to work.

Has anybody else experienced this? I'm using the latest version of the SDK on Snow leopard.

(My Mac has also completely frozen twice today to the extent that only turning it off at the mains seemed to revive it so not a good day).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have enough disk space on your mac.

Then go and delete your build directory in the project.  Close xcode, open it back up.  Try to build.

Hope that works, its just a guess.

Comment: Plenty of space on Mac. 

I did remove completely the build folder  and so far the issue has not reoccured so perhaps it was a permissions error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have disk/file problems. Check the permissions on the files and directories in the projects build folder. If you've lost permission for one of the files, the clean will fail.

Comment: Might as well blow away the build directory.  It's the same thing as doing a clean all targets and will guarantee you don't have any permission errors down there.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac froze? Twice? On the Same Day? Seems your Mac is in serious disorder, I would look for this first. Maybe the build problems are just another symptom of a bigger issue.

Comment: I had added memory a few days before. I did a full apple hardware test and everything seemed to be fine. So far, it hasn't frozen again. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Also, apart from checking out Xcode's logs in Console.app and posting anything interesting, did you install Xcode 3.2 from the Snow Leopard DVD before installing the iPhone 3.1.2 SDK for Snow Leopard?

If you upgrade to Snow Leopard (w/ Xcode 3.1 installed), and then immediately install the latest iPhone SDK (before installing Xcode 3.2 from the Snow Leopard disc), you may experience grave problems like this one. I know I did.

Comment: Didn't see anything helpful in the console. Re how I did the upgrade, I didn't chose to install xcode 3.2 when upgrading to Snow Leopard. However, it's possible that I may have installed the developer tools from the DVD when installing Leopard ages back. Not sure if that would mean when doing the Snow Leopard upgrade, it would update the dev tools as well.